# How can I get the next element of an array in C?

Tags: c

I am new to C, and I have to create a transliterator for my hw assignment at university. In Polish, the sound [tsh] as in chair is represented by two letters: "cz". I have to create a program that will turn every "cz" into 4 (F.e. zaskoczony = zasko4ony). I have a char array(defined at the beginning of the program) and  I can get "c" and change it to anything I want, but I'm struggling with getting "z" checked, because I cannot get the +1 element in my string array.

I've tried putting i+1 into the array's brackets, tried using a variable, but nothing seems to work.

```
while(i<100){

    intText[i] = someString[i];

    if(intText[i] == 'c'){
        int increasedI=i+1;
        printf(" %d", increasedI);

        if(intText[increasedI] == 'z'){
            printf("4");
        }
    }else{
        putchar(intText[i]);    
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Think a little more about the logic... If the character is not a `'c'` then print it as it is. *Else* check if the next character (at index `i + 1`) is a `'z'`, if it is then increase `i` by one and print `4`. Else (if the character at index `i + 1` is not `'z'`) then print the character `'c'`.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-replace-word-text-another-given-word/amp/) help?

Comment: You need to answer a simple question in your mind. Does `i` count input characters or output characters?

Comment: As a general advise, try making a description in human language. Follow those steps while strictly refraining from making guesses (computers don't either). If this gives you the right results, start coding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get the next element of an array in C?

`someString[i + 1]`

---

A problem with OP's code was that it did not advance `i` an extra 1 nor populated `intText[increasedI]` before using it.

```
if(intText[i] == 'c'){
    int increasedI=i+1;
    printf(" %d", increasedI);

    // if(intText[increasedI] == 'z'){
    if(someString[increasedI] == 'z'){
        printf("4");
    }
    i++;  //add
 ....
 i++;
```

Also string processing should stop when the *null character* is reached, not `i== 100`.

```
// while(i<100){
while(someString[i]){
```

---

Keep separate indexes of reading and writing.  Walk down the string, making the desire substation.

As long as the substitution string, example `"4"`, is no longer than the source, `"cz"`, we can do an in-place substitution.

```
// in-place substitution
size_t in_index = 0;
size_t out_index = 0;

// Loop until end-of-string
while (someString[in_index] != '\0') {
  // Test for special combination
  if (someString[in_index] == 'c' && someString[in_index + 1] == 'z') {
    in_index += 2;
    someString[out_index++] = '4';
  } else{
    someString[out_index++] = someString[in_index++];
  }
}
someString[out_index] = '\0';
puts(someString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank everyone for your helpful advice which helped me find my own solution. This is the code which meets my expectations and looks quite simple.

```
int main()
{
    char someString[100] = "cenczetkczacczka";
    int i = 0;
    while(someString[i] != '\0'){
        if(someString[i] == 'c' && someString[i + 1] == 'z'){
            printf("4");
            i++;
        }else{
            putchar(someString[i]);
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```